# Unable to install Bolt 2.0 on Qnap NAS

Tags: php, bolt-cms

I'm trying to install Bolt 2.0 on a Qnap NAS which latest firmware comes with PHP/5.3.29. I've read Bolt requires at least PHP/5.3.3 so I guess I've to wait for a Qnap update.

I'm wondering if the error is related to the outdated PHP version or does it indicate a different problem?

```
PHP Fatal Error: Vendor Library

Error: Class ' ��' not found
File: vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.php
Line: 59
```

Line 59 refers to:

```
$attributes = $attributes ?: new AttributeBag();
```

Which is part of:

```
public function __construct(SessionStorageInterface $storage = null, AttributeBagInterface $attributes = null, FlashBagInterface $flashes = null)
{
    $this->storage = $storage ?: new NativeSessionStorage();

    $attributes = $attributes ?: new AttributeBag();
    $this->attributeName = $attributes->getName();
    $this->registerBag($attributes);

    $flashes = $flashes ?: new FlashBag();
    $this->flashName = $flashes->getName();
    $this->registerBag($flashes);
}
```

Comment: Err no, 5.3.29 is significantly later than 5.3.3 - 26 minor revisions later. Is this file trying to load a PHP file on line 59? If so, what?

Comment: Line 59 refers to:
    $attributes = $attributes ?: new AttributeBag();

Comment: Try a manual `require_once()` on the `AttributeBag` class. I wonder if you have saved the files in the wrong character set - if a manual load works, try re-saving in UTF-8.